# How to install dotnetcore in windowsservercore docker container

Tags: c++, docker, x86, .net-core

I have C++ application and it is running via ASP.NET Core application. The C++ application is x86 based, so it is not running in aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver images.

I read about nanoserver containers and it supports x64 based application. I am unable to build my C++ application as it has dependencies with x86 libraries.

So I use windowsservercore images, which supports both  x86 and x64 applications. Tested my C++ application in container commandline and it is working fine.

But this image does not have dotnetcore installed, so please let me know how to install dotnetcore in windowsservercore container. Suggest me windowsservercore image with dotnetcore.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Docker installed and working on your desktop, then it is not hard to create your own docker image that will install dotnetcore onto a windows server image.
Something very like this should serve your purpose:

```
FROM microsoft/iis:windowsservercore
COPY dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe C:\
RUN C:\dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe /quiet /install
```

Interpret this dockerfile as

1. Start with the windowsservercore image
2. Copy `dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe` into the image
3. Run it.
4. Save the result as my docker image.

In order to make this work you should

- Create a working directory directory on your machine
- Save the above `Dockerfile` in this working directory
- Download `dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe` into the same working directory from https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.4-download.md
- On the commandline, CD to the directory and run the docker build command:

  `docker build -t MyDotNetOnServerCoreContainer -f Dockerfile`

It's worth an hour of your time to go through the tutorial on making Dockerfiles.

Comment: Although your implementation is straight-forward, it requires the exe on the build agent which is clunky from an automation perspective.  Did you consider installing Chocolatey and then doing a Chocolately installation of .NET Core?

Comment: I kind of lost my enthusiasm for chocolatey– I think my build automation approach would be, to add one more line -- `RUN curl https://.../dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe` to the Dockerfile?

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Using dotnet-runtime-2.0.4-win-x64.exe to copy makes COPY command fail. rename it by removing dashes and priods. It will work.